# MySQL query is taking long time after index is rebuilt, but then works fast... why?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with 3M records and a simple unique index on an integer field. When selecing

```
SELECT * FROM ThisTable ORDER BY ThatField LIMIT 10
```

It works very fast, as expected. When I insert or delete a record though, or restart MySQL, this same query takes like 10-20 seconds, sometimes longer.

I am guessing that it's loading index into memory - that's great, but why client should wait? Can this be fixed so that the query returns fast always?

Thank you very much for your help,
Andrew

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way you'll be able to get this query into cache as soon as the engine restarts is to run the select as soon as the engine restarts.

A script file that restarts the MySQL process, and then immediately logs into the MySQL server and executes `SELECT * FROM ThisTable ORDER BY ThatField LIMIT 10` will ensure that the query is cached immediately, meaning that the next query should be nicely cached.

Comment: @KOHb This process is commonly called "warming the cache' or "warm up cache". It's a common process for sites that depend on the caching layer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... When do I need to run this cache "warm up" query exactly? On every update/delete done to ThisTable? But this could be an overkill, no?

Comment: And this script involves restarting of MySQL process, I think it's definitely not something you want to do on every update. Could you please clarify? I have multiple users working with the web site, and I don't really want to restart MySQL every time someone makes a change in that table.

Comment: @KOHb - that's only good for when you restart MySQL. Sorry I missed the part about "insert or delete".